# Flutter - How can i cancel FCM notification from ios device when app is closed?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, flutter-local-notification

I made an application with Flutter. The application has webrtc and users can call each other. When someone get call we send call notification with custom sound. The problem is right here. In scenarios such as the call not starting or the person not seeing it, the sent call notification should be deleted from the device. I can do this on Android device. But I don't know how to do this on iOS device. Can someone help?

I added the "tag" parameter to the notifications for the Android device. I solved my problem on android devices with this method. But I couldn't find a similar parameter for iOS devices. Is there a different method for deleting notifications on iOS devices?